# Save dialog for string writer

Tags: c#, asp.net, savefiledialog

I am using the below code to export data to csv format. Normally its stored into the system desktop. i want to save various location thats why need save dialog. But i can't do this please help me to do it..

### My partial code is here :

```
       StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        var columnNames = dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Select(column => column.ColumnName).ToArray();
        sb.AppendLine(string.Join(",", columnNames));
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        { var fields = row.ItemArray.Select(field => field.ToString().Replace(","," "));
        sb.AppendLine(string.Join(",", fields));
        }
        File.WriteAllText(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) +"/test.csv", sb.ToString());
```

Comment: You are aware that ASP.NET runs on a server, and not on your own computer (unless of course on your local IIS)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to open up a Save Dialog, you need to add the content-disposition header to your response as so:

```
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=test.csv");
```

Now you can write the string to the response:

```
Response.Write(sb.ToString());
Response.End(); //VERY IMPORTANT
```